# How do I open a Link Portal?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance

I received a Streetpass for Kingdom Hearts 3D Dream Drop Distance and I can't seem to access the Link Portal. How do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a Link Portal in Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance, you will have to ensure that the touch screen is zoomed in. Take a look at this picture I found on [Google](http://google.com/images):

[image: Touch Screen of Kingdom Hearts 3D]

Notice how the magnifying glass has a **negative symbol** inside of it (many people refer it to as "zoom out). This means that the screen has been zoomed in. To do this, just press the magnifying glass whenever it has the **positive sign** (also known as "zoom in").Next, you approach a Link Portal, and a Pink bubble will pop up. Click on the bubble and you can use the Link Portal! I hope this has helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have the ability to access the Link Portal s I have missed.